# Passing an array as command line argument for linux kernel module

Tags: linux, arrays, command-line, linux-kernel, kernel

I would like to pass an array of data to the Linux kernel module.

In the kernel:

```
 int a[5]; 
 int count;
 module_param_array(a, int, &count, 0);
```

But I've no idea how to pass values from the command line. If it is a just variable I will use:

```
insmod k1.ko a=10
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass arrays via

```
 insmod k1.ko a=10,20,30,40
```

see [Linux Kernel Module Programming](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/linux_kernel_module_programming_2.6/x323.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: @Jayy: would you mind accepting this as solution to your question ?

Comment: have a look at [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on how you accept a solution on stackoverflow.com.